# TBB Free Image lambda array comparison error

Tags: c++, for-loop, parallel-processing, tbb

I hae been playing around with Thread building blocks with Free Image Plus on linux. I have been trying to compare the speeds between a sequential and parallel approach when subtracting one image from another, however I noticed that the final outcome when using the parallel approach generates some anomalies that I am unsure now to solve and am in need of some advice.

my question is: Why does the image seem to generate more array comparison errors when using parallel but work fine when using sequential (The image is supposed to be black with a few white spots, so the white pixels in the second image are comparison errors between the 2 image pixel arrays (of type RGBQUAD)).

RGBQUADs are declared before the call to these methods and act as global variables.

```
RGBQUAD rgb;    
RGBQUAD rgb2;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF8RS.jpg "Sequential".

```
for (auto y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for(auto x= 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        inputImage.getPixelColor(x, y, &rgb);
        inputImage2.getPixelColor(x, y, &rgb2);
        rgbDiffVal[y][x].rgbRed = abs(rgb.rgbRed - rgb2.rgbRed);
        rgbDiffVal[y][x].rgbBlue = abs(rgb.rgbBlue - rgb2.rgbBlue);
        rgbDiffVal[y][x].rgbGreen = abs(rgb.rgbGreen - rgb2.rgbGreen);
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZulZ.jpg "with TBB parallel".

```
parallel_for(blocked_range2d<int,int>(0,height, 0, width), [&] (const blocked_range2d<int,int>&r) {
    auto y1 = r.rows().begin();
    auto y2 = r.rows().end();
    auto x1 = r.cols().begin();
    auto x2 = r.cols().end();

    for (auto y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
        for (auto x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
            inputImage.getPixelColor(x, y, &rgb);
            inputImage2.getPixelColor(x, y, &rgb2);

            rgbDiffVal[y][x].rgbRed = abs(rgb.rgbRed - rgb2.rgbRed);
            rgbDiffVal[y][x].rgbBlue = abs(rgb.rgbBlue - rgb2.rgbBlue);
            rgbDiffVal[y][x].rgbGreen = abs(rgb.rgbGreen - rgb2.rgbGreen);
        }
    }
});
```

I believe it may have something to do with passing the reference pointer inside a lambda that is copying values by reference anyway as this is the only thing I can think of that may affect the process. (rgb, rgb2). I have observed that If I change the parallel for blocked range to height and width, this solves the issue, however this then defeats the point of using a parallel method in the first place.

Comment: Please show how and where rgb & rgb2 are declared. If these variables are supposed to temporarily store pixel colors, maybe you just need to move the declarations into the lambda, making variables local to each thread.

Comment: That makes sense, as each thread will be saving over the variable causing the a race condition, will try ad change this now.

Comment: Yep that did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If these variables are supposed to temporarily store pixel colors, maybe you just need to move the declarations into the lambda, making variables local to each thread. – Alexey Kukanov.

Variables were indeed placed outside the bounds for the lambda so each thread was modifying the referenced variable causing a race condition where one thread would try to read the data from the variable as another was modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is put a spin mutex lock around the update (The last three lines of the inner loop where you are storing the result.)  This will slow the program down a lot but will tell you if there is a synchronization problem with your update.  (It is not obvious, but you are storing adjacent values in the same cache lines for some of the results.   Testing is the only way to answer this.)

If it is, you can do atomic swaps to update the result, but that is super-expensive.  If not, sorry I didn't spot your problem.

Even if this is not a problem, you might get better performance by using a 1-D `blocked_range` which is cache-aligned.  I'll leave it to you to do the gory implementation.